# How to assign independent of [(ngModel)] in *ngFor list and select HTML tag

Tags: html, angular, forms, drop-down-menu, ngmodel

I have a problem with [(ngModel)], it syncs all my select to variable

my variable is selectStations = [];

So, when I select an option inside, it will render all select to select the same one and assign to all slot in a variable (see the picture below, just look at it override all slot that is available)

Typesript:

```
      stations: StationModel[] = [];
      selectStations = [];   
    
      addSlotSelectStation(){
        this.view.loading = true;
        this.selectStations.push(null);
        console.log(this.selectStations);
        this.view.loading = false;
      }
      addSelectStation(index: number, stationId: string) {
        console.log(index);
        this.selectStations[index] = stationId;
      }
      deleteSelectStation(index: number): void{
        this.selectStations.splice(index, 1);
        console.log('delete index', index);
      }
```

HTML:

```
     <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addSlotSelectStation()">
         add slot
     </button>
```

```
<!-- List Group All -->
        <ul class="list-group overflow-auto">
          <!-- Loop List All Select Station -->
          <li
            *ngFor="let selectStation of selectStations; let index = index"
            class="list-group-item"
          >
            <div class="form-inline">
              <!-- Order Number -->
              <span class="mr-3">{{ index + 1 }}</span>
              <!-- Selection Dropdown -->
              <select
                #selectnow
                class="form-control bg-light col mr-3"
                name="selectStation[{{index}}]"
                formControlName="selectStation"
                size=1
                [(ngModel)]="selectStations[index]"
                (change)="addSelectStation(index, selectnow.value)"
              >
                <option selected value="">choose station...</option>
                <option
                  *ngFor="let station of stations"
                  [value]="station.id"
                >
                  {{ station.name }}
                </option>
              </select>

              <!-- For test debug reasons -->
              <div>{{ selectStations[index] }}</div>
              <div>{{ index }}</div>

              <!-- Delete Select Station -->
              <button
                class="btn btn-outline-info"
                (click)="deleteSelectStation(index)"
              >
                X
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Result:
[image]

So That's the problem, I want it just select only one, and assign value only one each selector, not override another selector value.

Comment: Try  [(ngModel)]="selectStations[index].id". The connection between your select and your values, it has to be the same.

If your options have an id value, your select, has to be connected with that id.

Comment: How?,  my variable selectStations is an array and I collect only a stationId within it, or do I need to change from stationId to keep the StationModel object?

Comment: Can you shared your code on Stackblitz?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much time, But i will change from ngModel to FormArray. I think that it may fix something. Thank you for your help If I have any update I will ans my own question here

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] I change it from [(ngModel)] to use FormArray. That's very useful when it come across iterating in the list of input/dropdown and etc.

This Link is super useful, Check it out! :)
[Angular Reactive Forms: The Ultimate Guide to FormArray](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a)